# Trying to Save Multiple Data to Database - Laravel

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel, store

I try to save multiple data with same ID to database

[image]

So here I got the **SQL error** because attribute "student_profile_id" is not same format as the databse.

Then I try to decode it, but get the **"Array to String"** error.

Here is my code:

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Classes;
        $user->class_name = $request->class_name;
        $user->teacher_profile_id = $request->teacher_profile_id;

    $user->student_profile_id = json_encode($request->student_profile_id);

    dd($user);
$user->save();}
```

View:

```
 <select type="text" name="student_profile_id[]" id="student_id" class="form-control">
   <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
        @if($student)
        @foreach($student as $data)
    <option value="{{$data->id}}"> {{$data->student_name}}</option>
         @endforeach
         @endif
 </select>
```

Anyone can help me on this? How can I store the multiple data that use one ID

Comment: what is the array "["1","2"]" represent? two student_profile_id s?

Comment: @OMR yes, it represent two data from student_profile_id. I edit the question with my view. I hope it can make you clear.

Comment: the relation between Classes and student must be classes hasMany students, you should rebuild your relation based on that,

Comment: if you want to save the student_ids in json field, you could, but it must be named student_profile_ids, but this way you will lose the relation